# Student input in secondary teacher evaluations

Tags: secondary-education, reference-request, teacher-evaluations

this is something I have been wondering about for a while now.  In my school district (urban setting in Pennsylvania) student input amounts to exactly 0% of the final assessment for observed teachers.  however, student performance, in the form of standardized test scores, amount a large percentage of a teachers final performance rating.  Do any other states/countries take student input into consideration when evaluating teachers? if so, how does this look?  I know from the peers I have spoken with that none of them have encountered student input being taken into consideration in the various rating systems at their districts.  is there any research-based reason for this?

Comment: K-12 is more paternalistic and top-down than university education, where I believe student evaluations are a relatively recent thing historically. You ask if there's any research to support not using evaluations in high school. Is there any research to support using them at the college level?